# GRE Subject Test - Past Papers, Books, Advice

Tags: reference-request, big-list, advice, online-resources, gre-exam

This is not for the Maths part of the General GRE. This is for the GRE [Subject Test](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about) in [Maths](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about/content/mathematics). Feel free to add or comment.

- [How do I know the definition of rings or of anything on the GRE given that definitions can vary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967070)
- [What does the subject GRE measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470560)
- > I think trying to relearn an entire undergraduate degree's worth of mathematics purely for this test would be an enormous waste of precious time and energy. You can't make this test your life,you have other priorities. I'd begin talking to graduate students who have been through the test-see what they'd recommend. - [Mathemagician1234](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/792069)

---

http://www.mathematicsgre.com/

http://www.physicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1078

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Schaum's outlines "Advanced Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists" has some excellent ODE, linear algebra, and complex problems that mimic the ones I have seen on practice exams.

Answer (score 127):

### Top web resource:

[DM Ashura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DM_Ashura) aka [Bill Shillito](https://www.mathsub.com/): https://www.mathsub.com/

---

### Official resources:

(Official) 0568

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE1.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE1.pdf)

http://web.archive.org/web/20150701191646/http://rambotutoring.com/GR0568-solutions.pdf
http://online.fliphtml5.com/ebvz/nytg/
https://web.archive.org/web/20161023164437/http://online.fliphtml5.com/ebvz/nytg/#p=1

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%202.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%202.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%202%20solutions.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%202%20solutions.pdf)

---

(Official) 1268 aka 1768

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%201.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%201.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%201%20solutions.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%201%20solutions.pdf)

http://seansmathematicsblog.blogspot.hk/2016/08/solutions-to-math-subject-gre-sample.html
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qQg_AuKUglUnd6YWIyYWNudWM/view?usp=drive_web

[http://webpages.sou.edu/~stonelakb/math/testprep](http://webpages.sou.edu/%7Estonelakb/math/testprep)

http://www.rambotutoring.com/GR1268-solutions.pdf

https://www.scribd.com/doc/315056948/GR1268-Solutions
https://www.scribd.com/user/285425100/RG

http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?t=3494
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uVGGkZosoPcGVRcDNPN0d2ZVU/view

---

(Official) 9367

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE2.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE2.pdf)

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%203.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%203.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%203%20solutions.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%203%20solutions.pdf)

http://seansmathematicsblog.blogspot.hk/2016/08/solutions-to-mathematics-subject-gre.html
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qQg_AuKUglY0I1bkZ5azl6NDQ/view

---

(Official) 8767

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE3.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE3.pdf)

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%204.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%204.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%204%20solutions.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%204%20solutions.pdf)

http://seansmathematicsblog.blogspot.hk/2016/08/solutions-to-mathematics-subject-gre_7.html
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qQg_AuKUgld2hoV3h0OFBaZHM

---

(Official) 9768

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE4.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE4.pdf)

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%205.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%205.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%205%20solutions.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/Practice%205%20solutions.pdf)

---

(Official) 35-item practice test

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math97-99.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math97-99.pdf)
[https://www.geneseo.edu/~johannes/GRE%20Practice%20Problems.pdf](https://www.geneseo.edu/%7Ejohannes/GRE%20Practice%20Problems.pdf)

---

(Official) ETS Major Field Test in Mathematics Sample Questions

https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/MFT/pdf/mft_mathII.pdf

[http://www.wou.edu/~beaverc/404/S14/major%20field%20test.pdf](http://www.wou.edu/%7Ebeaverc/404/S14/major%20field%20test.pdf)

---

### Web resources:

[Rambotutoring.co](http://rambotutoring.com/)m practice test and answers

http://www.rambotutoring.com/GREpractice.pdf
http://www.rambotutoring.com/GREpracticeanswers.pdf

---

More practice tests (rea i think)

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math01.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math01.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math02.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math02.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math03.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math03.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math04.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math04.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math05.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math05.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math06.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math06.pdf)

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math01e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math01e.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math02e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math02e.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math03e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math03e.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math04e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math04e.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math05e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math05e.pdf)
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/othertests/math06e.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eiacoley/gre/othertests/math06e.pdf)

---

GRE Subject Test Math Practice (App)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.varsitytutors.learningtools.gresubjecttestmath&hl=en

---

Sheir.Org GRE Mathematics Sample Questions

http://www.sheir.org/gre_mathematics_sample_questions.html

http://www.sheir.org/gre-mathematics-sample-test.html

---

Sheir.Org GRE Mathematics Practice Test

http://www.sheir.org/gre_math_practice_questions.html

http://www.sheir.org/gre-math-practice-test.html

http://www.sheir.org/gre-math-subject-test-practice.html

http://www.sheir.org/gre-mathematics-subject-test-practice.html

---

FPSC Mathematics Lecturer Test Sample Questions

http://www.sheir.org/fpsc-math-sample-questions.html

---

FPSC Mathematics Lecturer Test Past Papers

http://www.sheir.org/fpsc-mathematics-past-papers.html

http://www.sheir.org/fpsc-mathematics-past-test.html

http://www.sheir.org/fpsc-mathematics-past-test-papers.html

http://www.sheir.org/math-lecturer-past-papers.html

http://www.sheir.org/mathematics-lecturer-test-past-papers.html

---

Sample Questions (1-10) FPSC Mathematics Lecturer test BS-17.pdf

[Mathematics Subject test sample questions MCQs (21-30).pdf](https://www.scribd.com/doc/311749932/Mathematics-Subject-test-sample-questions-MCQs-21-30-pdf)

[Mathematics Subject test sample questions MCQs (31-40).pdf](http://documents.mx/documents/mathematics-subject-test-sample-questions-mcqs-31-40.html)

Mathematics Subject test sample questions MCQs (41-50).pdf

---

UCLA Christian Parkinson

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~chparkin/gre.html](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Echparkin/gre.html)

---

UCLA Charlie Marshak

[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GREWorkshop.html](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GREWorkshop.html)

[https://web.archive.org/web/20160911233702/http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GREworkshopProblems.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911233702/http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GREworkshopProblems.pdf)
[https://web.archive.org/web/20160911233717/http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GREworkshopSolutions.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911233717/http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GREworkshopSolutions.pdf)

[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE/Problems/GREBootcampProblems.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE/Problems/GREBootcampProblems.pdf)
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE/Solutions/GREBootcampSolutions.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE/Solutions/GREBootcampSolutions.pdf)

[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE/GREProb.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE/GREProb.pdf)
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE/GRESol.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecmarshak/GRE/GRESol.pdf)

---

UCSB

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015.html](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015.html)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_syllabus.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_syllabus.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture1.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture1.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture2.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture2.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture3.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture3.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture4.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture4.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture5.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture5.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/lecture%206.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/lecture%206.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture7.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture7.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture8.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture8.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture10.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_lecture10.pdf)

[http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_practice_test.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/math_gre_w2015_practice_test.pdf)

---

Clark University Study Group for the GRE Subject Test in Mathematics

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/GREmath/](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/GREmath/)

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/GREmath/linalg.pdf](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/GREmath/linalg.pdf)

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/GREmath/linalgDiscuss.pdf](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/GREmath/linalgDiscuss.pdf)

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/GREmath/highcalc.pdf](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/GREmath/highcalc.pdf)

---

SubjectMath.Com

http://media.wix.com/ugd/57c670_fb82db77a2134bd6836923eda969cda6.pdf

http://media.wix.com/ugd/57c670_a4c54c95e72c44aa8944ef3172ec6f25.pdf

http://media.wix.com/ugd/57c670_2d7c1c187d394b8aa39d14cc3bf4665e.pdf

http://media.wix.com/ugd/57c670_5deab4f8898941cf8eed1f07bb339fb9.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXoZ8n72v5M

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LYugb1LO9g

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPPMAVwz59Y

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2xJWoD95_k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84nZMwr7saU

---

GRE Subject Calculus

https://www.coursehero.com/file/10329376/GRE-Subject-Calculus/

GRE Subject Additional Topics

https://www.coursehero.com/file/10329377/GRE-Subject-Additional-topics

---

> UChicago has a very large list of unique questions that I don't see linked here (if it is, sorry I just missed it!). See: [math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/) – Jonathan Rayner

---

> Just found a YouTube channel called ProfOmarMath - has a selection of good videos discussing content and dissecting GRE questions. See [youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBiVnG9A5gceFbk7oTBHALETI2SUmplIL](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBiVnG9A5gceFbk7oTBHALETI2SUmplIL) - Jordan Mitchell Barrett

---

### Book resources:

1. Morris Bramson --> I think this is better than REA because Bramson tests more on understanding while REA tests more on knowledge. Idk. Disagreements welcome.

https://www.coursehero.com/file/14751549/Morris-Bramson-Mathematics-Subject-Test-AdvanceBookFi-org/

---

2. REA (rated low by [DM Ashura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DM_Ashura) aka [Bill Shillito](https://www.mathsub.com/))

https://books.google.com/books?id=Njk8Ea2IAU0C

[https://www.amazon.com/GRE-Mathematics-Test-Preparation/dp/0738608386](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0738608386)

REA_GRE_MATH_SUB.pdf

---

3. Princeton

[https://www.amazon.com/Cracking-Mathematics-Subject-Test-Edition/dp/0375429727](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0375429727)

Quote: This book is for GRE Math Subject Test, NOT for GRE General Test.

Cracking The Gre Math Sunject Test.pdf

Cracking+the+GRE+Mathematics+Subject+Test(2010).pdf

Typos

http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?t=38
http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?t=1432
http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=234
http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?t=234

-

Calculus Practice

https://www.coursehero.com/file/p2an7lo/P-A-21-B-16-C-15-D-12-E-10-78-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5/

-

UCI

http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/First-Day-Test-.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2011/09/multivariable_calculus.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2011/09/more_calculus_from_test2.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2011/09/calculus_practice_test3.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2011/09/ALGEBRA_REVIEW1.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2011/09/linear_algebra_from_test2.docx

http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-1.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-2.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-3.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-4.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-5.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/chapter-6.pdf
http://sites.uci.edu/gremath/files/2013/08/Chapter-7.pdf

---

### Web resources (Advice)

GRE advice&strategy - be realistic

Post by j0equ1nn » Sat Apr 04, 2009 4:08 pm

http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=217

Maths SE questions

[recommending books for GRE math subject test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269549/recommending-books-for-gre-math-subject-test)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/math-gre-subject-exam

[Multivariable Calculus for GRE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807285/multivariable-calculus-for-gre)

[Books to study for Math GRE, self-study, have some time.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91170/books-to-study-for-math-gre-self-study-have-some-time)

[GRE Math Subject Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217697/gre-math-subject-test)

[Ultimate GRE Prep](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791162/ultimate-gre-prep)

---

### Maths SE Tags:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gre-exam

http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gre

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gre

---

### Resources suggested to me:

- http://academicpublishers.in/site/book_details/competitive-mathematics/mathematics-for-competitive-examinations
- https://mualphatheta.org/past_tests#tests2018
- http://scherk.pbworks.com/w/page/14864231/Quiz%3A%20Linear%20algebra

Comment: This was really kind of you to share. Do you have an opinion on the REA books if you have used them?

Comment: @qbert I think I agree with what a lot of people say: topics are too difficult for GRE.

Comment: Do we have solutions to the 35 tests above? It will be helpful to counter check after completing each test. Anybody please

Comment: @PrinceKhan You make one then edit to add :P

Comment: @BCLC Good idea :P

Comment: Do you have a download link for REA_GRE_MATH_SUB.pdf ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Hint: I don't have a download link for "REA_GRE_MATH_SUB.pdf" ;) Anything further might get the site or me into trouble.

Comment: @qbert re REA: see edit on bramson

Comment: UChicago has a very large list of unique questions that I don't see linked here (if it is, sorry I just missed it!). See: https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/

Comment: @JonathanRayner I've noticed here lately the test getting more difficult, and, in some problems, very convoluted.  Do you think that's why they made their problems unique?

Comment: I don't know if it's the motivation, but it's certainly of value seeing as there's little other "harder" questions publicly available. My current recommendation for study strategy is do all official past exams, then rambo test, then all uchicago. If someone can do all of uchicago quickly and accurately, I think the test will be a breeze as those problems are equal or a bit harder than the actual exam (at least when I did it recently).

Comment: Just found a YouTube channel called ProfOmarMath - has a selection of good videos discussing content and dissecting GRE questions. See https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBiVnG9A5gceFbk7oTBHALETI2SUmplIL

Comment: I've tried the Sheir.Org practice problems listed above. Quite a few problem statements missed information, and some answers are wrong. Very problematic, definitely not recommended, unless the student has a strong enough background to distinguish right from wrong.