# If $a<g(x)<x$ on the interval $(a,b)$, why must $g$ be nonconstant? (GRE question)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, gre-exam

I have the following GRE question that I have some trouble seeing.

If $g$ is a function defined o the open interval $(a,b)$ such that $a < g(x) < x$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then $g$ is

A) an unbounded function

B) a nonconstant function

C) a nonnegative function

D) a strictly increasing function

E) a polynomial function of degee 1

I answered that D), because I thought I could take the derivative on the inequality $a < g(x) < x$ and get $0< g'(x)<1$, showing that the equation is strictly increasing. However the answer says it should be B) and I don't really see how they concluded this. Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Umm.... where did you get the idea that if $f(x) < g(x)$ that $f'(x) < g'(x)$ that is simply not true and not justifiable.

Comment: You've made a serious blunder: $f(x)<g(x)$ does not imply $f'(x)<g'(x)$.

Comment: For example $x<3-x$ on $(0,1)$ but $1\nleq-1$. In essence, any constant on the first inequality has no effect on the second

Comment: @Emilio: even simpler, $1<2$ but as functions their derivatives are both identically zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I completely missed that

Comment: I only pretended to invert the inequality but that's great!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1922417/140308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g(x) = c $ is constant.  Than $a < c < x$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.  But there must be some $y \in (a,c)$.  $a < y < c=f(y)$.  A contradiction.

So $g$ is not constant

====

It's worth noting for $g(x) \not \in (a,b)$ we can have $g(x)$ do anything.  So C,D, E aren't possible answers.  A) and B) are only possible if the are "forced" to be unbounded or non-constant on $(a,b)$.  For A) $g(x)$ is actually forced to be bounded so A) is not correct.

It's also worth noting $g(x)$ need not be increasing on $(a,b)$ it can bounce around all it wants in $a < f(x) < x$.

Comment: sorry for my post. I was typing on my silly phone, while yours went up.

Comment: Great minds and all that...

Comment: You have a typo, $c=f(y)$ instead of $g(y)$

Comment: How can $g(x)$ not be in $(a,b)$?  The function is only defined for $x\in(a,b)$, and for all such $x$, $a\lt g(x)\lt x\lt b$.

Comment: Hmm, the first three or four times I did not read this as $g(x)$ was only defined (a,b) but read it as a real function defined everywhere but with a certain behavior on (a,b).  Not sure why I read it as such.  Something about the wording made me feel it wasn't that sophisticated/abstract.  But you are right.  of g:(a,b)->R then g exists nowhere else.  If it only exists on (a,b) then A) is false as it *is* bounded, C) could be false as a or b could be negative, E has no reason to be true. D) the function can fluctuate in its bound.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \gt g(x)$ = $c \gt a$, where $c$ is constant, than $\exists y$ $\in$ (a,b), such that $y \lt c$. Therefore, $g(y) $ = $c \gt y$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiation is not monotonic, unlike integration.

[image]

[GRE Subject Test in Mathematics - Where can I find related past papers, solutions to those, sample tests, advice, books, apps or other resources?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1922417/140308)