# GRE question $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{x \in \mathbb R} (e^x-nx)$

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum, gre-exam

How would you solve this question?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{x \in \mathbb R} (e^x-nx)$$

I found it in a GRE exam but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Where did you find that please? Include [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922417) if not yet there please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}\left(e^x-nx\right) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^1-n\right)=-\infty$

Comment: I don't understand why you chose x = 1 to get $(e^1 - n)$ , couldn't you just have easily chosen x = -1 to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (e^{-1}  + n) = \infty$?

Comment: I could.  But knowing that the limit is less than $\infty$ isn't very helpful.