# Determining which of the following Quotients is a Field

Tags: ideals, finite-fields, gre-exam

I took the GRE Math Subject today and I had a question regarding quotients. Let $I = (X^2 + 2)$. For $F = \mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_5, \mathbb{Z}_7, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$, determine which fields satisfy the condition that $F[X]/I$ is a field.

Since each answer choice only listed one field, I figured that the first four were in their own category while $\mathbb{R}$ was different so that $\mathbb{R}$ was the correct choice. I am thinking that my answer was correct because $X^2 + 2$ is separable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $F[X]/I$ is a field $\iff x^2+2$ is irreducible in $F$. Also $x^2+2$  is irreducible in $F\iff $ it has no roots in $F$

Comment: Now just check which $F$ satisfies the above and you are done!

Comment: @RishabhPant isn't $\mathbb{R}[X]/I = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No ,@Timkinsella; $\Bbb R[X]/I\cong \Bbb R(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^2+2=0$

Comment: oh right. ma bad.

Comment: So it has no roots in $Z_5, Z_7, Q$
Edit: ....stupid me thought $\sqrt{2}$ was a solution

Comment: [GRE Subject Test - Past Papers, Books, Advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922417)