# Mathematics GRE subject test Prerequisites

Tags: advice

I looked at the Mathematics GRE subject test's website and it says the material covered is 50 % Calculus, 25 % Algebra, 25 % Additional Topics.
I have taken two semesters of real analysis, abstract algebra, linear algebra, and complex analysis as far as pure math. Is this enough for the mathematics GRE subject test (does anyone know from personal experience)? What I'm worried about is that I have not taken discrete mathematics/graph theory/combinatorics nor have I taken a topology course with Munkres.  Do you think my course preparation is enough (assuming I review etc..)? Thank youl

Comment: Yes. Discrete math / graph theory / combinatorics is nothing to know, just common sense. Yes.

Comment: Try to find the old tests written by the ETS.

Comment: Afaik, GRE tests only basics of discrete math, graph theory, combinatorics and number theory. I'm planning to try Rosen Discrete Maths. [GRE Subject Test - Past Papers, Books, Advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922417). Anyhoo as an applied maths person, I consider your background excellent. I have to study complex analysis and abstract algebra on my own. Thank God number theory is already part of studying abstract algebra. That's my bias but I think you may be better off more on revision than the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who's taken the GRE twice and dozens of practice tests, admittedly a long time ago, although no major changes have happened since then, you'll be fine.  Make sure to practice.

Official ETS prep:
https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf

A really helpful resource with more official ETS prep:
[https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~iacoley/greprep.html](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eiacoley/greprep.html)